# Finding a JSON Object based on the results of a deep search using JSONPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have JSON that looks something like the following.  I want to get the Attribute.Name / Attribute.content pairs where Name.Text[?(@.content == 'All-Inclusive Mgmt')]

I had thought something like

```
Attribute[?(@.Name.Text.content == 'All-Inclusive Mgmt']
```

might work.. but that fails when (I'm using Java Jayway JSONPath )

Can anyone help?  This has to be pure JSONPath, if that's possible

```
{
"Attribute":[
    {"Name":
{"Text":[
    {"content":"All-Inclusive Mgmt","Language":"ENG"},
    {"content":"??????","Language":"ZHT"}
]},
"Value":
{"Text":
 [{"content":"?","Language":"ZHT"},
  {"content":"Yes","Language":"ENG"},
  {"content":"Oui","Language":"FRE"},
  {"content":"Si","Language":"ITL"},
  {"content":"Si","Language":"SPN"},
  {"content":"Ja","Language":"GER"},
  {"content":"??","Language":"JPN"}
 ]
}
},
{"Name":
 {"Text":[
     {"content":"All-Inclusive Fees","Language":"ENG"},
     {"content":"??????","Language":"ZHT"}
 ]},
 "Value":
 {"Text":
  [{"content":"?","Language":"ZHT"},
   {"content":"Yes","Language":"ENG"},
   {"content":"Oui","Language":"FRE"},
   {"content":"Si","Language":"ITL"},
   {"content":"Si","Language":"SPN"},
   {"content":"Ja","Language":"GER"},
   {"content":"??","Language":"JPN"}
  ]
 }
}

]
}
```

Comment: `I want to get the Attribute.Name / Attribute.content pairs` sorry but in Json Path is all getting one (type) of data. Not the parent element along then the child element. What do you want first the parent  `Attribute.Name` or the ` Attribute....content` ?

Comment: In this case I would be happy to get first element in the Attribute[] array, if that element.Name.Text.Content == "All Inclusive Mgmt".  Once I have that specific element, I can extract the correct nodes.

Answer (score 0):

this path here

```
$.Attribute[*].Name.Text[?(@.content=='All-Inclusive Mgmt')]
```

will give you

```
     { 
      "content":"All-Inclusive Mgmt",
      "Language":"ENG"
    }
```

this is the content with value *All-Inclusive Mgmt*

Comment: But I also need the Attribute.Value  So basically, in my example, for the array index where name.text.content == All Inclusive Mgmt, I also need value.text.content where language = 'ENG'

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fetch what you want step by step as follows:

**Code Snippet**

```
DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonStr);
List<Map<String, Object>> textName = jsonContext.read("$.Attribute[*].Name.Text[?(@.content == 'All-Inclusive Mgmt')]");
System.out.println(textName.toString());

String language = textName.get(0).get("Language").toString();
System.out.println(language);

String expr = String.format("$.Attribute[*].Value.Text[?(@.Language == '%s')]", language);
List<Map<String, Object>> tectValues = jsonContext.read(expr);
System.out.println(tectValues.toString());
```

**Console Output**

> [{"content":"All-Inclusive Mgmt","Language":"ENG"}]
>   ENG
>   [{"content":"Yes","Language":"ENG"},{"content":"Yes","Language":"ENG"}]

Then you can further combine the results into a single object.